# std::async won't spawn a new thread when return value is not stored

Tags: c++, multithreading, asynchronous

Consider I have lamba `foo` which just does some stuff and doesn't need to return anything.
When I do this:

```
std::future<T> handle = std::async(std::launch::async, foo, arg1, arg2);
```

Everything runs fine and the lamba will be spawned in a new thread.
However, when I don't store the `std::future` which the `std::async` returns, the foo will be run in the main thread and block it.

```
std::async(std::launch::async, foo, arg1, arg2);
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Perhaps the ```future``` returned by ```async``` is immediately destroyed. I wouldn't be surprised if ```future```'s destructor has an implicit wait inside.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

From `just::thread` [documentation](http://www.stdthread.co.uk/doc/headers/future/async.html):

> If policy is `std::launch::async` then runs `INVOKE(fff,xyz...)` on its own thread. The returned `std::future` will become ready when this thread is complete, and will hold either the return value or exception thrown by the function invocation. The destructor of the last future object associated with the asynchronous state of the returned `std::future` shall block until the future is ready.

In

```
std::async(std::launch::async, foo, arg1, arg2);
```

The returned future is not assigned anywhere and its destructor blocks until `foo` finishes.

Answer (score 6):

I would like to add a link to an article by Herb Sutter on [async and ~future](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3451.pdf) in which he argues that futures should never block.

Comment: It's not an article but a proposal. Other than that, yeah, making `~future()` block was a mistake.

Comment: ~future() does not actually block by default. It blocks only when returned from std::async, because async assigns a blocking state to future and ~future() has to release it.

Comment: > async assigns a blocking state to future...
@WojciechCierpucha but why is that?

Answer (score 3):

Why blocking?

> 1. `std::async();` returns `std::future` **temporary object**
> 2. **temporary object** is destroyed immediately, calling  desctructor.
> 3. `std::future` destructor is blocking. It is bad and troublesome.

Why assigning is ok?

> By assigning to a variable, the returned object is not destroyed immediately, but later, until end of scope of your calling code.

Code Example: `main1` is ok. `main2` and `main3` are equivalently blocking the main thread.

```
void forever() {
    while (true);
}

void main1() {
    std::future<void> p = std::async(std::launch::async, forever);
    std::cout << "printing" << std::endl; // can print, then forever blocking
}

void main2() {
    std::async(std::launch::async, forever);
    std::cout << "printing" << std::endl; // forever blocking first, cannot print
}

void main3() {
    {std::future<void> p = std::async(std::launch::async, forever);}
    std::cout << "printing" << std::endl; // forever blocking first, cannot print
}
```

Take a look at [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/future/async/)

**Return value of std::async**
When launch::async is selected, the future returned is linked to the
end of the thread created, even if its shared state is never accessed:
in this case, its destructor synchronizes with the return of fn.
Therefore, the return value shall not be disregarded for asynchronous
behavior, even when fn returns void.