# How to use std::async with void method with no parameters?

Tags: c++, asynchronous, future, stdasync

I'm assuming there's something very simple I'm missing about `std::async`. I'm trying to run 2 `void` methods asynchronously, with no return values.

```
#include <future>

class AsyncTestClass {

    public:
        void Initialize()
        {
            std::async(&AsyncTestClass::AsyncMethod1);
            std::async(&AsyncTestClass::AsyncMethod2);
        }

        void AsyncMethod1()
        {
            //time consuming operation
        }

        void AsyncMethod2()
        {
            //time consuming operation
        }
};
```

But get an error when calling my `AsyncMethod1` or `AsyncMethod2` within `std:async`:

> Substitution failed: type 'typename std:conditional<sizeof....(ArgTypes) == 0, std::_Invoke_traits_Zero<void, typename std::decay.....is ill formed with _Fty = void (AsyncTestClass::*)(), _ArgTypes =

What is the proper usage of `std:async` with `void`, parameterless methods? The examples I see seem similar to how I'm using it, but it's not working for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`AsyncTestClass::AsyncMethod1`, being a non-static member function, can only be called if an instance of `AsyncTestClass` is supplied. You probably meant this:

```
std::async(&AsyncTestClass::AsyncMethod1, this)
```

This creates a `std::future` object whose value will be obtained by evaluating `this->AsyncMethod1()`.

By the way, the return value of `std::async` should be assigned to a variable, otherwise the call will block. See [std::async won't spawn a new thread when return value is not stored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9490405/stdasync-wont-spawn-a-new-thread-when-return-value-is-not-stored). If you have C++20, the compiler will catch this for you thanks to `[[nodiscard]]`.

Comment: Oh, very nice, I didn't know async has `[[nodiscard]]` added to it from C++20.